# How to extract the names of persons who like a facebook page?

Tags: java, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to extract the details of persons who like a particular page. I tried to get it using many ways tried different API's restfb and facebook4j but still not even getting id of a person who likes a particular page. I somehow extracted JSON of a particular page.but it does not contain the details of persons who like the page. If that should also be extracted through json data or any other way then it should be easy for me to recursively call each id and pass it so I can extract more details of that particular person. Plz help me to resolve this

```
private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException 
 {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int cp;
while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) 
{
  sb.append((char) cp);
}
return sb.toString();
}
public static JSONObject readurl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException
{
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
try 
{
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  String jsonText = readAll(rd);
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
  return json;
} 
finally
{
  is.close();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
JSONException,  FacebookException 
{
  try
  {

  JSONObject json = readurl("https://graph.facebook.com/"pageid);
  System.out.println(json);}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For obvious privacy reasons, this is not possible. You can get the pages a user likes with the "user_likes" permission, the other way around.

After all, what would you do with the list of users who like a page? You would not be allowed to contact them or use their data anywhere.

About scraping, see the Facebook terms: https://www.facebook.com/terms.php

> 3.2:  You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots,
>   robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission.

Comment: when I pass a keyword for eg "icecream" i want to get the details of those who like that particular page for my pjt. I am not interested in contacting them. So is it possible through any api's

Comment: it isn´t, because that would still be a privacy issue.

Comment: is there any other way or are u trying to say that it's impossible

Comment: it is thankfully not possible. i would not want any app i did not even authorize to know if i liked a specific page. and you would not even be allowed to use that data for anything at all.

Comment: but I want to do this for my pjt  and build an network to know the relations between them

Comment: is it posible via web crawlers(crawler4j)

Comment: again, it is not allowed to do this, even if it would be possible. don´t try to hack and think about privacy.

Comment: i´ve added the link to the facebook terms to the answer

Comment: now i would like to know why i got a -1 for my answer, it is 100% correct imho. would be nice to know what´s wrong with it, for improvement.